# How to read a c# server side value in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I've a JArray response value like below

```
{[
  {
    "id": "90b254dc-3fcd-4e7c-9943-59bce366ccdc",
    "invoice_number": "510002500007368" 
  }
]}
```

i'm getting this value from c# class ..when I try to read in jQuery like below ways

```
  var tmp = '@Model.Transactions';
    var tmp = Model.Transactions;
    var tmp = @Model.Transactions;
```

from that I'm getting the values like below image ... i need a structured values. let me know if any idea.. thanks

[image: Response Value Image]

Comment: put values in hiddenInputs:

@var counter=1;
@foreach(var item in Model.Transactions)
{
<input type="hidden" id="id'+@counter'"  value=@item.id>
<input type="hidden" id="invoice_number'+@counter'"  value=@item.invoice_number>
@counter=counter +1 
}

<input type="hidden" id="counter"  value=@counter>


<script>
for (int i=1;i<counter;i++){
 tmp_id=document.getElementById("id"+i);
temp_invoice=document.getElementById("invoice_number"+i);
}
</script>

Comment: this @var counter=1 not taken in .cshtml

Comment: @{ var counter= 1 ;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render it in a "raw" manner like this, without escaping or encoding so it will remaing "correct" JSON:

```
var tmp = @:Model.Transactions;
```

You can also for example prepare your JSON string in the controller e.g. `Model.MyJson` then use `@:Model.MyJson` in the view (notice `:` after `@`).

This is shortcut for `@Html.Raw(myJson);`